# Postgres 12 patching

Tags: postgresql, installation, rhel7

Unable to find postgres 12.13 installer for Rhel 7

I just need to patch my postgres. where can I find postgres 12.13 installer?

My current config:

- Postgresql 12.5
- Linux RHEL 7

I am planning to install 12.13 binaries in a different location and backup/restore the databases onto the new version? is there any other best way to do it?

Comment: You don't need an installer. You just run `yum update postgresql-12` (or something along those lines)

Comment: Regarding backup, restore and different location you may have a look into [E.1. Release 12.13](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12-13.html) and [E.4. Release 12.10](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12-10.html). As long as your installation is utilizing [https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/](https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/) you might be able to do an inplace upgrade via `yum update ...`. Overall the question seems not to be about programming at all but related to server or database management and operation and would fit on other stack sites more.